# What is causing this "possible loss of precision" error?

Tags: java, final

I am having problem with my final variable. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This is my first code which is working fine

```
final int i = 90; 
byte b = i ; 
System.out.println(i);
```

Here is my second code which says ***possible loss of precision***. What is wrong here?

```
final int i; 
i = 90;
byte b = i ; 
System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: @Manuel Selva: But the first version is working. how?

Comment: @Pshemo, why the edit?

Comment: @Mr.Pandey Does the first code compiles?

Comment: @Nick To make example shorter, better formatted and easier to read.

Comment: You should provided a title that covers the subject of your code. There are probably hundreds of questions with a title like "Why is my code not working?"

Comment: @CommuSoft:Next time i will be more specific about the topic.

Comment: @sankrish: Yes, it does.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I couldn't find the exact reason about this in JLS, so I went through the byte code and found that *the reason is that the compiler couldn't **inline** the value of `i`* in the second case, but is able to do it in the first case.

Here's the code:

```
final int x = 90;
System.out.println(x);

final int i;
i = 90;
System.out.println(i);
```

The compiled byte code looks like:

```
 0: getstatic     #2        // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 3: bipush        90
 5: invokevirtual #3        // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
 8: bipush        90
10: istore_2
11: getstatic     #2        // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
14: iload_2
15: invokevirtual #3        // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
18: return
```

So in the first case (3 to 5), it directly uses the value `90` for printing, while in the second case (8 to 15), *it has to store the value into the variable and then load it back onto the stack. Then the `print` method will pick the top value of the stack.*

So, in case of the assignment:

```
byte x = i;
```

The value of `i` will be picked up from the stack at runtime, and not inlined by the compiler. *So the compiler doesn't know what value `i` might contain.*

Of course, this is all my guess. The byte code might be different on different JVMs. But I've the strong intuition that this might be the reason.

Also, [JLS §4.12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) might be relevant here:

> A variable of primitive type or type String, that is final and initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is called a constant variable.

Since in the second case, the variable is not initialized by a constant expression, but is later assigned a value, it is no longer a constant variable.

Comment: Whether the compiler applies an optimization or not has nothing to do with what the language spec says. Looking at IL is never required to understand language behavior. Only the last part of this answer is relevant.

Comment: @usr I did go to JLS first. I found that quote, but didn't really found the exact point there. So just went to `javap` for confirmation. I know byte code doesn't always give answers for the rules, but this was for inspection.

Answer (score 4):

Simply, the first way the compiler "knows" that 90 can fit into a byte variable, but in the second, it can't detect the value of "i" and has no idea what value it might contain and therefore not sure it could fit into a byte variable or not.

Comment: That is probably true, although you can then argue that the compiler is still at fault; even in the second code the value of i is and can only be 90 so it COULD know the truth. But perhaps from a compiler design point of view that is actually a hard problem to solve.

Comment: @Gimby: No, actually it's quite a simple thing for a compiler to check. Even basic compilers usually have a simple Constant propagation. However, AFAIK, the java compiler does perform nearly no optimization at all, because it relies on the JVM on performing optimizations during runtime.

Comment: I know there are some optimizations performed, but indeed most of it is at runtime. This is not an optimization though IMO, this is about code correctness.

Answer (score 2):

At the compile time compiler can determine the value of final variable if it is assign at the time of creation but in second code you are assigning the value after creation which will not catch by the compiler.

If you use more than 127 in first code (for variable i) it will not work too.

Spec says “*If a primitive type or a string is defined as a constant and the value is known at compile time, the compiler replaces the constant name everywhere in the code with its value. This is called a compile-time constant*”

And

**Compile time constant are:**

declared final

primitive or String

initialized within declaration

initialized with constant expression